# How does Sublime text compile php with HTML?

Tags: php, html

So, I tried. Hard.
And didn't find an answer.
So, here's my problem.
I have the following code for an HTML project I've been working on.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Feedback Form</title> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>Send Us Your Feedback!</h1>
<form action="send_mail.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Email Adress:</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email_address" value="" maxlength="100" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comments:</td>
<td>
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="comments"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And, (even though you cant see the actual page) I tried adding in php so that it would send me mail whenever some one imputed the required elements. I have all the code,

```html
<?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "lhm.bertler@icloud.com";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "feedback_form.html";
/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'] ;

/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/
function isInjected($str) {
 $injections = array('(\n+)',
 '(\r+)',
 '(\t+)',
 '(%0A+)',
 '(%0D+)',
 '(%08+)',
 '(%09+)'
 );
 $inject = join('|', $injections);
 $inject = "/$inject/i";
 if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
  return true;
 }
 else {
  return false;
 }
}

// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
elseif (empty($email_address) || empty($comments)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) ) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else {
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results",
  $comments, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

but what I'm not sure how to do is make both pieces of code work together. Help? (Basically, how do you connect a php document to an HTML one. Like js?)

Comment: You can use AJAX/XHR (JS) or you can rename your HTML document to a .php file and simply add the PHP code in before `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`

Comment: If it's using a POST request, a form input or AJAX/XHR is most likely necessary.

Comment: Problem is, if I do that, it just shows the code, not the page.

Comment: Are you testing it locally or on XAMPP/Website?

Comment: If you're testing it locally (just running the file on your desktop) it's not going to work. Chrome doesn't support offline PHP.

Comment: Oh. How can I get it to online php?

Comment: You can upload it to a website that has PHP support or you can download XAMPP. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: I downloaded XAMPP, but I cant figure out how it works